# C# Google Cloud Text-To-Speech Being - Wavenet Issue

Tags: c#, audio, google-cloud-platform, cloud, text-to-speech

**Dear Stack,**

I'm being charged on google cloud for using wavenet, despite the fact that the code im using is not using wavenet "i think", if I'm using wavenet, is there a way to disable it?

Here is my code:

```
// [START tts_synthesize_text]
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an audio file from the text input.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text">Text to synthesize into audio</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Generates a file named 'output.mp3' in project folder.
    /// </remarks>
    public static void SynthesizeText(string text, string filename)
    {
        TextToSpeechClient client = TextToSpeechClient.Create();
        var response = client.SynthesizeSpeech(new SynthesizeSpeechRequest
        {
            Input = new SynthesisInput
            {
                Text = text
            },
            // Note: voices can also be specified by name
            Voice = new VoiceSelectionParams
            {
                LanguageCode = "en-US",
                SsmlGender = SsmlVoiceGender.Female
            },
            AudioConfig = new AudioConfig
            {
                AudioEncoding = AudioEncoding.Mp3,
                SpeakingRate = 0.75
            }
        });

        using (Stream output = File.Create(filename))
        {
            response.AudioContent.WriteTo(output);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/pricing) page you was charged for WaveNet voice (minus free quota 1 million, 0.2673*16 = 4.28). WaveNet sound was set automatically since the “name” parameter in “[VoiceSelectionParams](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.texttospeech.v1beta1#google.cloud.texttospeech.v1beta1.VoiceSelectionParams)” was empty. You need to specify a “name” parameter otherwise “the service will choose a voice based on the other parameters such as language_code and gender.” Voice names you can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/voices) in column “Voice name”.